# Import Embedded Packet Capture output into Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, pcap, asr

I did packet capturing with cisco's Embedded Packet Capture and I would like to view the output in Wireshark.
The problem is that I only have CLI access to the device, so exporting via TFTP is not an option.
Can I somehow copy/paste the buffer output into Wireshark so it can interpret it?

https://www.codepile.net/pile/6oLYmw7A

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you “copy [filename] scp:” on the router to initiate an outbound scp (which uses ssh) connection?   Do you have physical access to the router to copy the dump to a usb: drive?

Comment: Cisco IOS has many different methods to copy files to/from a router using the CLI. In fact, you can use TFTP using the CLI. At the CLI, type `copy ?` to see the various options.

Comment: Unfortunately I have limited access to the device. I can reach it via 2 hop servers, on which I have only SSH command allowed.